# ajax call set the response in a div with specific tags

Tags: html, ajax

In my jsp page I have a call ajax which will render a specific text to be set in my page

This text contains a specific data:

```
<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="264,716,397,744" alt="Sun" href="Search.html?searchPathId=4" title="<spring:message code='label.cliquerIci'></spring:message>">     
</map>
```

This map is used for an image, when I reach the specific area in this image I wanna show a text from my resource bundle files.
But what is shown is

`<spring:message code='label.cliquerIci'></spring:message>`
This tag is not interpreted!

*More details:*

The ajax call:

```
 $.get("getLogigram.html", {
        id : id
        }, function(data) {
        $("#logigramId").html(data);
    });
```

In the java class I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getLogigram", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLogigram(HttpServletRequest request) {
    LogigramForm logigramForm = (LogigramForm ) request.getSession().getAttribute("logigramForm ");
    String idAsString = request.getParameter("id");
    if (idAsString != null && !"".equals(idAsString)) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(idAsString);
        Logigram logigram = logigramManager.getLogigramById(id);
        logigramForm.setLogigram(logigram);
    }
    return "logigram";
}
```

Logigram is a model mapped with the table logigram in the database.
The table logigram :

```
    id serial,
    name varchar(100),  
    path varchar(100),
    map text
```

for `return "logigram";` => here I will render a jsp page:

```
<%
    LogigramForm logigramForm = (LogigramForm ) request.getSession().getAttribute("logigramForm ");
%>
<img src="<%=logigramForm .getLogigram().getPath() %>"  usemap="#map" />
<%=logigramForm.getLogigram().getMap() != null ? logigramForm.getLogigram().getMap() : "" %>
```

map is just a column in the database which contains:

```
<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="264,716,397,744" alt="Sun" href="Search.html?searchPathId=4" title="<spring:message code='label.cliquerIci'></spring:message>">     
</map>
```

Comment: That looks like something that should have been interpreted server-side.  Which doesn't really have anything to do with AJAX.  What is your server-side resource that you're calling?  How should it interpret that code?

Comment: From my server, I just render the string which contains the map tag, and in my jsp I declared <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> this taglib should replace the tag spring:message, but this is not done

Comment: Elaborate more on "just render the string".  How specifically are you rendering that string?  What should cause that string to be interpreted by the Sprint Framework in some way?  This is a Spring Framework question, which you should probably indicate in your tags and in the description and in the code shown.  You need to provide information about this server-side resource and what specifically is happening there.

Comment: @David, I added all the code